# Get ElasticSearch simple_query_string to support fuzzy

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a record in my ElasticSearch index with the term "`cleveland`". When I do this search:

```
"query": {
    "multi_match": {
        "fields": [
            "firstname^3",
            "lastname^3",
            "home_address",
            "home_city"
        ],
        "query": "clevela",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
    }
},
```

it successfully finds the term. The missing two characters are within the fuzziness threshold. But I'd like to support the extended query syntax of `simple_query_string` (+, -, phrase search, etc.) So I tried this syntax:

```
"query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
        "query": "clevela",
        "fields": [
            "firstname^3",
            "lastname^3",
            "home_address",
            "home_city"
        ],
        "lenient": true
    }
},
```

and it does not find the term. Fuzziness appears to be turned off. How do I turn it on?

Answer (score 0):

In a simple query string, you need to specify the [fuzziness parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html#simple-query-string-syntax), by adding ~N (N is the max edit distance) after the search term. Modify your search query as

```
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "clevela~2",               // note this
      "fields": [
        "firstname^3",
        "lastname^3",
        "home_address",
        "home_city"
      ],
      "lenient": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that defeats the purpose of simple_query_string. You use it to pass through whatever the end user has typed into the search box. No end user will type ~2 after each word.